# How do I setup one-to-one relationship in nhibernate? (currently doesn't return the foreign object)

Tags: nhibernate, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have a User, some of which are an employee. This is a one-to-one relationship and not all users are employees.

When I get a user it doesn't seem to be bring back the employee information it just has it marked as null. I thought I have got my head around nhibernate but I have tried playing with so many properties on the mapping files and haven't got it working. Any ideas or pointers as to what I am doing incorrect?

User Class:

```
public class User
    {
        public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Username { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Forename { get; set; }
        public virtual string Surname { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

User Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Portal.Core"
                   namespace="Portal.Core.Data.Database">

  <class name="User" table="[Users]">
    <id name="UserID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Username" not-null="true" length="50" />
    <property name="Title" length="10" />
    <property name="Forename" length="50" />
    <property name="Surname" length="50" />

    <one-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" fetch="select" lazy="false" foreign-key="EmployeeID" />


  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee Class:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public virtual int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public virtual string RoomNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Employee Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Portal.Core"
                   namespace="Portal.Core.Data.Database">

  <class name="Employee" table="[Employees]">
    <id name="EmployeeID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="User" unique="true" column="UserID" class="User" fetch="select" foreign-key="UserID" ></many-to-one>

    <property name="RoomNumber" length="20" />
    <property name="JobTitle" length="20" />

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see is different from Ayende's example is that you specify a foreign-key tag. Maybe try stripping your mapping down to Ayende's [example](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-ltone-to-onegt.aspx) (Which by the way is the exact same scenario) and try adding the extra properties/attributes one by one?

Comment: Have tried his example. It is half working now in that if i create a new user and add an employee record to it, it works fine. When I try and merge two users together (update employee record to be attached to new user) it just seems to lose the link. NHibernate is so hard to debug :/

Comment: You are breaking the 'rules' when you do it like this - when you tell NHibernate that this is a one-one relationship - you are not allowed to let one end of the association shift to another end-point. Instead you should update or create the employee-record for the user that will remain after your operation.

Comment: To clarify - it sounds like your case isn't really a one-one relationship, but rather a compoenent.

Comment: +1 for help but how would I move an employee record to the new user then without breaking ties that employee record had in the system?

Comment: Also this article implies if the employee has its own table component can't be used? Do you know any more about this? Thank you!   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541649/is-it-one-to-one-or-component-nhibernate-mapping

Comment: @Andi: If you want to keep the one-to-one: You just copy the values to the staying user's employee-record (or new it, if it doesn't exist). That way you don't 'break' the rules as the original employee-record is either deleted with the deleted user-record or continues it's association with that one. About the component cannot be used: It is correct that component mapping can only work if data is in the same table - I don't know if you can update the schema?

Comment: I could update the schema but not everyone is an employee so makes sense for it to be a seperate table. Only problem with copying values over is anything linked to the old employee ID will break. Seems like a bit of an issue with nHibernate if you can't update a record in this way...

Comment: Actually, it is more that you don't want it to work like a 'real' one-to-one because you let the Id's shift. Thus, You need to handle the cascading yourself - in other words - it's not an issue with nHibernate, but rather that you are working against the idea of one-to-one. If I were you (and I'm not), I'd forget the notion of one-to-one and go with a many-to-one instead - and then manually enforce that only one user at a time can point to the same employee-record.

Comment: Marked this as answer based on your last comment :)